# Printing list in <ul>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, list, render

I want to print a new `<ul>` list of `<li>` movies.

I don't see any list nor elements.

I also get a warning:

> index.js:2178 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components
>
> in input (at index.js:54)
>
> in label (at index.js:52)
>
> in form (at index.js:51)
>
> in div (at index.js:50)
>
> in Movie (at index.js:70)

This is my code:

```
class Movie extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: '',
                  list: [],
                  checked: true
                 };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.addMovie = this.addMovie.bind(this);
    this.listMovies = this.listMovies.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });

  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.addMovie();
  }

  addMovie(value){
    this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, value] });
    console.log(...this.state.list);
  }

  listMovies(){
    return(
      <ul>
        {this.state.list.map((item) => <li key={this.state.value}>{this.state.value}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Movie name:
            <input name="movieName" type="text" value={this.state.movieName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            Favorite?
            <input name="favorite" type="checkbox" checked={this.state.favorite} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <button onClick={this.listMovies}>
          List Movies
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Movie />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I would really want to print only my Favorites movies

Comment: initially there is not movieName in your state. initialise movieName in state.

Comment: How do you plan to add a movie as favorite? Where do you keep that "favorite" info in your list? At this point you are trying to list all the movies.

Comment: Can you please share what exactly is the requirement  ? because your question says 'I want to print a new <ul> list of <li> movies.' It will be good if you can share exact requirement here so that we can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want a simple movies list with favorites. Not the best one but working code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
     state = {
      favorite: false,
      movieName: "",
      movies: [],
      filter: true,
    };

  handleChange = (event) =>
    event.target.name === "favorite"
      ? this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.checked })
      : this.setState( { [ event.target.name]: event.target.value } );

  handleSubmit = ( event ) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      movies: [...this.state.movies, {name: this.state.movieName, favorite: this.state.favorite }]
    });
  }

  listFavoriteMovies = () => (
      <ul>
        {this.state.movies
        .filter( movie => movie.favorite )
        .map( movie => <li>{movie.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );

    listAllMovies = () => (
      <ul>
        {this.state.movies
          .map(movie => <li>{movie.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );

  changeFilter = () =>
    this.setState( prevState => ( {
      filter: !prevState.filter,
    }))


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Movie name:
            <input name="movieName" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            Favorite?
            <input name="favorite" type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <p>Showing only favorite movies.</p>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.filter
            ? this.listFavoriteMovies()
            : this.listAllMovies()
            }
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.changeFilter}>Click toggle for all/favorites.</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: thank you very much! i a question for you... in `this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.checked })` what does `[event.target.name]` means? why the `[ ]` ??

Comment: i have another question... i get a warning if i use: `handleChange(event){...`. Why your function `  handleChange = (event) => {...
`  does actually works fine and not mine?

Comment: `[]` is a dynamic key example for objects. You can use variables as dynamic keys. Here we are using each input's name for this variable. Thanks to this we don't have to handle each input separately. My function is an arrow function, that is it. Yours is a regular one, if you use a regular one you need to bind it. This is the only main difference here. What is the warning?

Answer (score 0):

> if you initially pass undefined or null as the value prop, the
>   component starts life as an "uncontrolled" component. Once you
>   interact with the component, we set a value and react changes it to a
>   "controlled" component, and issues the warning.

In your code initialise movieName in your state to get rid of warning.

For more information check [here](https://github.com/twisty/formsy-react-components/issues/66)